# Auto Align of button

Tags: html, css

Hi

On our website I have a page where there are Buy Now buttons

https://www.nutricentre.com/m-300-herbs-hands-healing.aspx

The styling that controls this is

```
.item .price {
    color:#8c9c54;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*    
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 48px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 150px; 
    */
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}


.item a.blue_btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any idea how I can get this aligned in a straight line regardless of the text above?

Comment: What about fixing heights or `position: absolute` and bottom property equal to bottom padding + 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting a `min-height: 370px;` for the easiest solution.

You **do not** want to set a static height for this because if you have an item with a longer description it will not automatically add space but just cram everything in.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change the css of the button, but from the whole item:
just add:

```
.item{
    height: 380px;
}
```

Of course, you have to care about the maximum item-height: your value must not be less, or the price won't be visible anymore.

In this case, `min-height` would be the better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Add a static height to .item

```
height:375px;
```

The height:auto; declaration tells .item to expand as big as it needs to be to fit everything in, so the tops of the divs line up, but since they are different heights, the bottoms are staggered.

As some of my co-responders have noted, min-height is also an acceptable option, until you have an item with enough text that item expands past the min-height value, at which point they will begin to expand and stagger again.

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction: http://jsfiddle.net/v9grm/

Create a grid and with the help of `display: table` make the columns the same height. Then place the button at the bottom of the column with `position: absolute`.